# `sort' behaviour when one line is prefix of another

Tags: shell, sorting, posix, gnu-coreutils

The [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sort.html) specification does not seem to say anything about what happens when one line provided to the `sort` program is the prefix of another.

But I find that my copy (GNU coreutils 8.4) gives precedence to the prefix:

```
$ echo -e 'foo\nfoobar' | sort
foo
foobar

$ echo -e 'foobar\nfoo' | sort
foo
foobar
```

- Is this universal to all implementations of `sort`?
- Where is this behaviour defined?
- Can I rely on it?
- *Is this so because this is the universal definition of the word "sort" w.r.t. programming?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort order is defined by the current locale, which is all the POSIX spec has to say. Your current locale (and most locales, I suspect) will consider a prefix to be lexicographically smaller than the string itself.